# Get memory usage after each training epoch - Tensorflow version 1.15

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow1.15

I am using code that requires tensorflow version 1.15.

However, I would like to record the amount of memory used after each training epoch of a BERT model. In tensorflow version 2, this can be achieved by `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_usage`. How could I do the same with version 1.15? If it's not a feature of tensorflow, is there another way I could record memory use after each epoch?

Thanks in advance and apologies if simple question - a beginner

*EDIT: I am interested in GPU usage*

Answer (score 1):

Periodically call
[psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#memory)
to ask the OS about recent resource consumption.

```
import psutil

mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
print(mem)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! If you are familiar with tensorflow v1, where should this be placed? I'm unfamiliar with the ```tf.estimator.train``` jargon of the version, where no callbacks are available

Comment: Also I've just read the docs, this seems like measure of CPU use, I'm looking for GPU use -sorry, should have clarified